# What is the difference between using a VPN and using a SOCKS proxy through an SSH connection to a VPS?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, proxy

I will be traveling to the People's Republic of China soon.

I already have a VPS and have successfully used an SSH connection to my VPS as a SOCKS proxy in the past. Is it worth also getting a VPN? What's the difference?

If it makes a difference regarding the usability of either option: my phone uses Android and my laptop runs Arch Linux.

Comment: VPN is a network level solution where as SSH with a VPS is a application level solution. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: You need to understand what a VPN and proxy are and does as the two cannot be compared... a VPN is a way of tunnelling through unsecured networks so your communications cannot be viewed across these insecure hops. A proxy, on the other hand, is your application asking another computer to do the communication for you and it "relays" the requests. The proxy server may or may not communicate with the rest of the network (i.e the Internet) securely so your data may be compromised.

Answer (score 0):

There are Pros and Cons.

VPN can tunnel all your traffic and you do not need your application to support socks proxy. And you do not need configure each and every application to use SOCKS proxy. However, since many VPN use specific IP protocol, not all public Wi-Fi supports it. And it can often be blocked quite easily.

SSH, on the other hand, is based on TCP. You can normally use SSH tunnel on any public Wi-Fi. However, as mentioned above, your applications need to support SOCKS proxy (or you use special proxy tools like ProxyCap). While browsers all support socks proxy, many less common applications do not support socks proxy. Even Adobe Flash running inside browser does not always obey proxy.

Since you mentioned Android, SSH proxy is not supported natively. All the solutions I know require rooting the phone. Android has native support for several VPN protocol. But in my experience, it is quite buggy. There are also 3rd party VPN solutions such as Cisco's AnyConnect and no rooting is required.